0 length Iterable compatible with For Each loop in VBA
For me it looks truely unbelievable that in the VBA for Excel there is a For Each loop but I simply cannot create any kind of data that the loop iterates through 0 times (so the core of the loop is never executed).
Function GetChildren() As Variant()
  Dim children()
  GetChildren = children
End Function

For Each something In GetChildren()
  ' Do something
Next something

Is there anything that is

compatible with the For Each structure
there is no need to check (for errors, emptiness etc.) The client side should be simple
in exchange in the GetChildren I can put anything to fulfill

So I guess I'm looking for a data structure to return that I can loop through 0 times.
Thanks in advance

With the use of the Collection object there is 0 iteration.
Function GetChildren() As Object

  Set childrens = New Collection
  Set GetChildren = childrens
  
End Function

Sub caller()

For Each something In GetChildren
  Debug.Print TypeName(something)
Next something

End Sub

